# Dealing with $e^{n/4}n^{-(n+1)/2}(1^1 2^2...n^n)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove that \begin{align}e^{n/4}n^{-(n+1)/2}(1^1 2^2...n^n)^{1/n}\end{align}
>
> converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$.

**Hint**: The logarithm of the given sequence can be written as \begin{align}\sum_k^{n}f\left(\frac{k+\theta} n\right)-n\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\end{align}

where $f(x)=x\log x$.

*I have tried to write it but I was not successful. I got:
$\frac{n}{4}-\frac{n+1}{2}\log n+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log k$
However $\int_0^1 x\log x=\frac{x^2(2\log (x)-1)}{4}|_0^1$*

**Question**:

How can I simplify the expression into $\sum_k^{n}f\left(\frac{k+\theta} n\right)-n\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the current problem $\theta =0$ and thus log of the given expression tends to $(f(1)-f(0))/2=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$a_n=e^{n/4}n^{-(n+1)/2}(1^1 2^2...n^n)^{1/n}$$we show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln a_n=0$$Proof: We know that $$\ln a_n=\dfrac{n}{4}-\dfrac{n+1}{2}\ln n-\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\ln k=\dfrac{n}{4}-\dfrac{n+1}{2}\ln n-\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\ln k$$also $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\ln k=n\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[\dfrac{k}{n}\ln\dfrac{k}{n}+\dfrac{k}{n}\ln n\right] \right)=n\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{k}{n}\ln\dfrac{k}{n}+\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\ln n \right)$$since $\int_{0}^{1}x\ln xdx=-\dfrac{1}{4}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$ we may write$$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\ln k\sim n\left(\int_{0}^{1}x\ln xdx+\dfrac{n+1}{2n}\ln n\right)=-\dfrac{1}{4}n+\dfrac{n+1}{2}\ln n$$by substitution we obtain $$\ln a_n\sim 0$$therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=1$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have been reading your proof and there are two steps that are not clear to me.$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\ln k=n\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[\dfrac{k}{n}\ln\dfrac{k}{n}+\dfrac{k}{n}\ln n\right] \right)$. How did you include $\frac{k}{n}\ln(n)$? Secondly, How was it derived $\frac{n+1}{2n}$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the same problem. How did you obtain $ln(\frac{k}{n})$? How did the $1/n$ got inside the logarithm?

Comment: You're welcome. Notice that $\ln k/n+\ln n=\ln k$

Comment: also $$\sum_{k}\dfrac{k}{n}\ln n=\dfrac{\ln n}{n}\sum_{k}k=\dfrac{\ln n}{n}\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}=\dfrac{(n+1)\ln n}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Sorry for bothering again. But after manipulation based on your guidance I came up with the following expression $\frac{k}{n}\sum_\limits{k=0}^{n}\log(\frac{k}{n})-n\int_0^1 x\log x$ I cannot get rid of the first $\frac{k}{n}$. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea on how to make the $\frac{1}{n}$ disappear. Could you help me?

Comment: Sure! Which $\dfrac{1}{n}$ you mean?

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing but I have figured it out! Thanks!

Comment: It's ok and very nice to find it out. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

*Without the hint.*

Considering $$a_n=e^{\frac n4}n^{-(n+1)/2}\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk^k\right)^{\frac 1 n}$$ taking logarithms as you did
$$\log(a_n)=\frac n 4-\frac {n+1}2 \log(n)+\frac 1n \log\left(\prod_{k=1}^nk^k\right)$$and 
$$\prod_{k=1}^nk^k=H(n)$$ where $H(n)$ is the hyperfactorial function.

Using Stirling like expansions
$$\log(H(n))=n^2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left({n}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2}
   n \log \left({n}\right)+\left(\log (A)+\frac{1}{12} \log
   \left({n}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{720
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ where $A$ is Glaisher constant $(\approx 1.28243)$.

Then $$\log(a_n)=\frac{12\log (A)+ \log \left({n}\right)}{12n}+\frac{1}{720
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ Continuing with series
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=1+\frac{12\log (A)+ \log \left({n}\right)}{12n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

This also gives a good approximation of $a_n$. For example
$$a_{10}=\frac{9\ 21^{7/10} e^{5/2}}{625 \sqrt{2}}\approx 1.04505$$ while the above approximation would give
$$1+\frac{\log (A)}{10}+\frac{\log (10)}{120}\approx 1.04406$$

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152599/equivalent-of-a-product/2152682#2152682